# Interbase (Firebird) com WampServer

Tags: php, firebird, wamp

Não consigo fazer funcionar o `php_interbase` no meu servidor WAMP, descomentei a linha do `php.ini` e mesmo assim o PHP não reconheceu.

Meu `Wamp` é o 2.5 em 64x com PHP 5.5, uso `Windows 64 bits`. Instalei o `Firebird` na minha máquina também, na versão 2.5 só que em 32 bits.

Alguém sabe o que mais posso fazer?

Comment: Olá, sugestão, não usa o WAMP ainda mais se você não vai usar o M-MySQL já que vai usar Firebird... Instale apenas o PHP e o FireBird e teste se conseguiu ativar a lib "php_interbase" via Prompt do Windows, não precisa nem do Apache. Depois que a lib estiver OK aí você instala o Apache.

Comment: Preciso usar o Wamp por causa de algumas razões especificas e não vou usar só o firebird pra ele. Obrigado.

Comment: Eu tive esse mesmo problema. Tive que instalar o WAMP 32 Bits e o Firebird 2.5 de 32 Bits. Depois disso você tem que ir nas configurações do WAMP e habilitar 1 opção no php.ini. Depois siga essas instruções: http://taylorlopes.com/wampserver-php-5-3-e-firebird-2-5-resolvido/